# How does one use python globals() to update a dictionary variable?

Tags: python, global

Assigning a string, integer, and so on with globals() works fine:

```
 
>>> globals()
{'__builtins__': , '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
>>> globals()["a"] = 5
>>> a
5
>>> globals()
{'__builtins__': , '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, 'a': 5, '__package__': None}
```

However, trying to assign to a dictionary fails:

```
>>> globals()["b['c']"] = 5
>>> globals()
{'a': 5, "b['c']": 5, '__builtins__': , '__package__': None, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
>>> b['c']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

This is true even if "b" is already defined as a dictionary.

So, given a text string such as "b['c']", how do I assign b['c']?

Comment: `globals()["b['c']"] = 5`?  What is this supposed to do?  There's no variable with the name   `b['c']`.  Why are you trying to use this as a variable name?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but I'm almost certain you are going down the wrong path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't imagine what you're trying to do here.

`b` doesn't seem to exist in globals already. You can't assign to a dictionary that doesn't exist.

Conceivably, you could do this:

```
globals()["b"] = {'c': 5}
```

which makes `b` a new dictionary containing one key, `c`, with a value of 5. But I'd think carefully about why you think you need to modify globals in the first place - there's almost certainly a better way to do what you want.

Comment: As I said, the problem is the same even if b exists in globals() as a dictionary. Having said that, your answer is correct: you don't assign the dictionary value in globals() as a string representation of the variable name, you assign it as the individual pieces.

Comment: When you use globals()["xx"]  you are acessing the variable name as a string - thus, on your example the variable you are trying to acess is  "b['c'] ' as a  whole, not a variable b, from witch you retrieve the index['c']. @Daniel Roseman, though gave the right way to do it didn't seem to understand this as well.

Answer (score 3):

The dictionary returned by `globals` may have a key for every global variable, but not every key in that dictionary needs to correspond to a global. Specifically, `b["c"]` is not a single global variable, but a syntactic structure for accessing the value that `b` associates with `c`. The following does work (but isn't necessarily recommended):

```
>>> b = {}
>>> globals()["b"]["c"] = 1
>>> b
{'c': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

How would you assign to a dictionary contained in a dictionary?

```
>>> outer = {'inner': { 'foo': 'bar' }}
>>> print outer['inner']['foo']
bar

>>> outer['inner']['foo'] = 'baz'
>>> print outer['inner']['foo']
baz
```

`globals()` just returns the *dictionary* in which global variables are stored. The variable names are the keys. So you access it (and any nested structures inside it) the same way you would with any other dictionary.

```
>>> globals()['outer']['spoon'] = 'fork'
>>> print outer['spoon']
'fork'
```

If you find this confusing, just break it up into one step at a time using more intermediate variables:

```
>>> g = globals()         # fetch the globals() dictionary into g
>>> o = g['outer']        # fetch the outer dictionary from g into o
>>> o['spoon'] = 'fork'   # store 'fork' under the key 'spoon' in o
```

Try to do that same "breaking up into smaller steps" with your attempted syntax, and you'll find that you get:

```
>>> g = globals()         # fetch the globals() dictionary into g
>>> g["b['c']"] = 5       # store 5 under the key "b['c']" in g
```

Here you've inserted a value with into a dictionary with the key `"b['c']"`. Which is a perfectly fine thing to do with a dictionary, so you don't get any errors. But it's utter nonsense mapped back to variables.

What you've done corresponds to the creation of a variable with the name `b['c']`. Not a variable named `b` referring to a dictionary with a key `'c'`. There is no way to actually refer to this variable without going through `globals()`, because that's not a valid Python identifier. Every time you try to write it out Python will just interpret it as you referring to a key inside a variable named `b`.